# Must I add properties for a class inherited in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to kivy and I really don't get why we need to state that the ball has no object property. Why can we just leave it blank without a property or is unnecessary to state properties for each instance of a class called within another. 
This is from Kivys Official documentation for a [tutorial for a PongApp](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html).

```
class PongBall(Widget):
    #Code Here
    pass
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Comment: I can't find the cited lines in https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html. It certainly does not make sense to write `ball = PongBall()` when it is overwritten in the next statement. In the tutorial, they write only `ball = ObjectProperty(None)`. This is explained in the section _Adding Ball Animation_

Comment: ```class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)```Sorry, This was the way it was put.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:  I really don't get why we need to state that the `ball` has no object property

The line `ball = ObjectProperty(None)` creats a new empty **instance class object**, you are using later on.
Without this instance you could not assign e.g. `self.ball.center = self.center`

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))
```